# is there a way to show Uitableviewcell selection on limited frame?

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, uitableview

i have a uitableview cell added some labels something like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell"; 

 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 if (cell == nil) {
     cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

     UIImage* myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"AccessoryForDealsMain.png"];
     UIImageView *MyimageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
     MyimageView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
     cell.accessoryView=MyimageView;
     [MyimageView release];

     UILabel *BluePatti = [[UILabel alloc] init];
     BluePatti.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,4,44);
     BluePatti.backgroundColor = BLUEPATTI;//[UIColor blueColor];
     UILabel *BlackLine = [[UILabel alloc] init];
     BlackLine.frame=CGRectMake(3,0,1, 45);
     BlackLine.backgroundColor = BLACK_LINE;
     [BluePatti addSubview:BlackLine];
     [BlackLine release];

     [cell.contentView addSubview:BluePatti];
     [BluePatti release];

     UILabel *Seperator = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
     Seperator.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:234/256.0 green:234/256.0 blue:234/256.0 alpha:1.0]; //[UIColor lightGrayColor];
     Seperator.frame = CGRectMake(4,43,316,1);
     [cell.contentView addSubview:Seperator];
     [Seperator release];
}
if(indexPath.section==5)
{
    cell.textLabel.text=[self.GenderCellData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.textColor=CELL_TEXT_COLOR;
    cell.textLabel.font=CELL_FONT;
}
else
{
    cell.textLabel.text=@"Cells";
    cell.textLabel.font=CELL_FONT;
}
return cell;
}
```

now when i touch cell it shows blue selection above all subviews.How do i change selection frame and colour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom [selectedBackgroundView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006938-CH3-SW9) in `UITableViewCell` that has your own frame and color. This will be shown when the cell is selected instead of the default blue background.

For example:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 30, 40)];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = view;
[view release];
```

Comment: but it's shown on complete cell.i have used this.I just want to show selection on limited frame but still no success

Comment: yep, I'd agree that you can't set your own frame. Doesn't work for me anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem today , and I solved via this code

**First , Inside my custom cell init**

```
     self.customerbgImageview = [UIImageView new];
    [self.customerbgImageview setFrame:CGRectMake(0 , 11, Width, 66)];
    [self.customerbgImageview setBackgroundColor:UIColor_RGB(0, 255, 255, 0.5)];
    [self addSubview:self.customerbgImageview];
```

**Second set selectionStyle none**

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

**third in the table method**

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    CustomOrderTableViewCell *cell = (CustomOrderTableViewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.customerbgImageview setHidden:NO];

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    CustomOrderTableViewCell *cell = (CustomOrderTableViewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.customerbgImageview setHidden:YES];
}
```